# How to resolve command php not found after installation in ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: php, ubuntu-21.04

I want to install specific version of php for that i write this command `sudo apt-get install php7.2` it's showing like this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php7.2-common' for regex 'php7.2'
Note, selecting 'php7.2-sodium' for regex 'php7.2'
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php7.2' for regex 'php7.2'
Note, selecting 'php7.2-thrift' for regex 'php7.2'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 235 not upgraded.
```

after this when i want to know the version of php , i run `php -v` i am getting following error

`Command 'php' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install php7.4-cli  # version 7.4.16-1ubuntu2.1, or sudo apt install php-cli     # version 2:7.4+76ubuntu1`

Comment: PHP 7.2 is pretty outdated (EOL Nov 2020). Why do you expect a current Ubuntu to provide such an old version of PHP?

Comment: i am doing one project that is running on php version 7.2

Comment: PHP 7.2 is [end of life](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). The project running on it **needs** to be updated.

Comment: @Quentin sometimes you MUST use an older PHP version, e.g. for a work project. I must use PHP 7.0 due to working specifications...

Answer (score 3):

Try these steps:

1: Add Ondrej's PPA, which contains the PHP 7.2 package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

2: Update:

```
sudo apt update
```

3: Install PHP 7.2

```
sudo apt install php7.2
```

4: Select the standard version of PHP

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

5: Restart Apache2:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands it will work

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install ca-certificates apt-transport-https

wget -q https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg -- I sudo apt-key add echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/stretch

main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list 
sudo apt update

sudo apt install php7.2
```